# registerForActivityResult is null after changing theme

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two fragments, when i click button it should send you to another fragment , but if previously I change theme and then click the button it wont work.
Here is the button click in one fragment :

```
override fun onClickEvents() {
        binding.buttonStartExam.setOnClickListener {
            AppPreferences.hasSeenGameInstructions = true
            val intent = Intent()
            activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            activity?.finish()
        }
    }
```

And here is the other fragment where the launcher is null :

```
private var resultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                startGame()
            }
        }
```

The resultLauncher is outside the onCreateView and out of onViewCreated, maybe I should save something on saved instance but how to save it?

Comment: Are you saying `resultLauncher` is null, and how are you determining that?

Comment: yes, i am using debug, it goes to resultLauncher but it says resultLauncher = null

Comment: If you put the breakpoint on the declaration line, it hasn't been initialized yet. The breakpoint stops the debugger *before* the assignment on that line takes place. In practice, it cannot possibly be null by the time the property is accessed elsewhere in your code unless you have a superclass constructor calling an open function that accesses this property in the subclass implementation.

Comment: Oh okay I understand, do you have an idea where the problem can be, or how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you can show more code...where and how you are changing the theme, and where and how you use this result launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because when you change a theme, activity is recreated and fragment is reattached to it. That is why you need to rebind your listener after Fragment is attached to Activity.
See more at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.
So, the solution would be:

```
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                startGame()
            }
        }
    }
```